# How to modify (default) Beamercolortheme?

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I created a latex beamer presentation using "Montepellier" theme with default color theme. I need to modify this theme (I want to change the color of the upper and lower border of header - separately).
So I copied "beamercolorthemedefault" to my project, renamed and included it (this is working!). But I can't change any colors - changing colors has no effect. I changed the default the this way (only the changed first lines):

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header:   

    /Users/joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemedefault.sty,v d02a7cf4d8ae 2010/06/17 09:11:41 rivanvx $


\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.3} % changed this

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=green!50!black}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamercolor{background}{parent=background canvas}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=yellow,bg=yellow} % changed this
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!100!green} % changed this
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!100!green} % changed this
```

But all this changes have no effect?! (replacing the complete content by another theme works)
So how to change any colors and how to change the borders of header?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you did something very complicated while the solution could have been much more easy. Moreover it is preferable to not modify the default `themes`: if you do it, at least change theme name.

For example, look at this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}

\makeatletter
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.3} % changed this

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=green!50!black}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamercolor{background}{parent=background canvas}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=yellow,bg=yellow} % changed this
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!100!green} % changed this
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!100!green} % changed this
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item hello again
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In a very simple manner I got:

[image]

[image]

If you want to create your own color theme, create a file called for example `beamercolorthememyct.sty` as:

```
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.3} % changed this

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=green!50!black}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=normal text}
\setbeamercolor{background}{parent=background canvas}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=yellow,bg=yellow} % changed this
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!100!green} % changed this
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!100!green} % changed this
```

You can put it in the same folder of your `.tex` presentation file (I have TeXLive and it works) or in your personal tree.

Then, the MWE shown above will become:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{myct}
\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item hello
\item hello again
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with the same two frames as graphical result.

> **EDIT**

To change just colors in the upper and lower line head you should use the proper keys. For example adding these lines to your `theme color`:

```
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}
```

allows you to get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is exactly what i did - i took the default theme and renamed it. And in meantime changing the "structure" via "\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.3}" is working (i get same result as you - i guess deleting tmp folder helped ;-)).
But main question remains how to change "structure" but only the color of upper and lower border of header.

Comment: thx! it works -> accepted

Comment: Thank you for downvoting! Please, could you leave a message to explain the reason such that I can try answering and maybe improve my post?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you could use headers and more comments on your code.