# Turning off all colors and background images in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds

Is there a command to turn off all colors in beamer ?

I have a tex file (beamer) where I have used a lot of colors. Just in case, the colors don't show well on the projector, I wanted to turn off all colors. I am looking for a single command to do this.

Is there a similar command to turn off the background images for all the frames too ?

I am using the theme: Juan-Les-Pins.

Comment: related: [making-latex-beamer-black-white](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639260/making-latex-beamer-black-white) and [how-to-modify-default-beamercolortheme](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54905/how-to-modify-default-beamercolortheme)

Answer (score 1):

For turning colors off (i.e. making them gray) add to the preambule:

```
\selectcolormodel{gray}
```

For turning off background images (assuming you are using `\usebackgroundtemplate` to set them) add to the preambule:

```
\renewcommand{\usebackgroundtemplate}[1]{}
```