# Beamer - Can't change slide background color

Tags: color, backgrounds

It seems like I can't change the background color, here is my header and my tests (none changes the background color of the slide, I manage only to change the color of the text):

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{biolinum}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
    \usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}


\begin{document}

    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
    \textcolor{white}{black} **here it changes only the text color**
    \end{frame}
    
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
    \begin{frame}{Test 2 }   
    Test             ** nothing changes from a standard slide **
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, is it like this link your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54905/how-to-modify-default-beamercolortheme

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer theme `focus` draws a background in color `normal text.bg`, so your change to color `background canvas.bg` has no effect. In the following example, the used color is changed to `background canvas.bg`.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}

% redefine beamer template "background canvas" with option "focus"
% originally defined in beamerouterthemefocus.sty
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@background canvas@focus\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{focus}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (0,0) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        % use color "background cavas.bg" instead of "normal text.bg"
        \fill[background canvas.bg] (0,0) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
    \textcolor{white}{black} **here it changes only the text color**
    \end{frame}

    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
    \begin{frame}{Test 2 }   
    Test             ** nothing changes from a standard slide **
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]